# Открытие файла по другому адресу

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте! У меня есть *php* файл по адресу `сайт/scripts/about.php`. Как сделать, чтобы он открывался по адресу `сайт/about.php`

Comment: нужно больше информация, какая CMS, какой фреймворк, дополните вопрос, иначе ответ вы не получите, т.к. ничего не понятно

Comment: @tCode да просто PHP файл. Да, такие тоже бывают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файле `.htaccess` включаете `RewriteEngine` и пишите следующее:

```
RewriteRule ^about\.php/?$ scripts/about.php [L]
```

Comment: Вроде бы работает, при открытии адреса сайт/about.php из GET массива выводятся нужные переменные: scripts и about.php, но отображается почему-то главная страница index.php с адресом сайт/index.php

Comment: @DoubleClick, не знаю. Функцию у себя проверил. Открывается нормально

Comment: Может ли как-то на это влиять строка DirectoryIndex index.php в файле .htaccess ?

Comment: @DoubleClick, возможно, но я не знаю. Вы простите, я не очень селён в `.htaccess`'е ) Что знал - то написал

Answer (score -2):

Какой вопрос - такой и ответ:
В корне сайта положить файл about.php в котором написать

```
<?php
include 'scripts/about.php';
```